# Skip test for sonar analysis

Tags: java, maven, code-analysis, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

What happens if I run following command :

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I have set Up sonar locally and its running on port 9000.

What would be impact of skipping test on sonar report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then Sonar won't produce any test related data, such as code coverage and test success statistics. This will also affect the calculation of the overall technical debt and total quality metrics.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi, yes it should. The best way to decide is to run the command yourself though :-)